# How to add JCE MediaBox popup to ajax content in Joomla articles

Tags: ajax, joomla, joomla-article, joomla-content-editor

I am displaying articles in ajax tabs and trying to add the [JCE MediaBox](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/products/jce-mediabox) popup to content in the article loaded by the ajax request.

Because the DOM is updated by ajax, and JCE MediaBox must be adding the event onload of the page, I am not able to attach the JCE MediaBox popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the ajax content, initialise the JCE MediaBox popup with this line of code:

```
window.jcepopup.create();
```